# Angular2 - How to watch service from directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Im currently new to angular2 and trying to implement a structural directive which attaches/ detaches the view according the presence of user role which is specified in the directive input.

Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Tp9WpqXk

How can I observe and subscribe to the CurrentUser.account changes and attach/ detach the view?

Thanks for your replies,
Danny

Comment: I think this post can help you https://netbasal.com/angular-2-making-your-component-auth-aware-982054048c8a#.c0ahd6yzp

Comment: Will read this, thanks